# Excel macro to search for text then Popup box if found

Tags: excel, vba

I'm not very experienced with Excel, but I'm wondering if its possible to make a macro to do the following:

I want it to search the whole worksheet(the sheet name is "Invoice") for the word "alert". If the word exists on the sheet I want a Popup box to appear.

Please let me know if its possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will create the msbox if it finds 'alert' on sheet Invoice:

```
Sub TestFind()

    Dim found As Variant

    Set found = Sheets("Invoice").Cells.Find("alert", Sheets("Invoice").Cells(1, 1), xlValues, xlPart)

    If (Not found Is Nothing) Then

        'found
        MsgBox "Found " & found, vbOKOnly, "Found"
    Else

        'not found

    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply, for some reason it's saying Subscript is out of range. Probably something I've done wrong....does it matter that I have 2 other worksheets? Although the one named invoice is the only one I need it for.

Comment: My instinct was correct, somehow I managed to mess it up but it's working perfectly now. Thanks a million!!!!!